# What are some uses for soy 'whey'?

Tags: food, cooking, soy

I was wondering what are some common uses for soy 'whey'
(leftovers from the coagulation process when making tofu)?
I usually use Calcium Chloride or lemon juice, for coagulation, if that makes a difference.

Comment: While not specifically about soy whey, this site has a lot of ideas for using whey, it may be worth trying a few out http://www.culturesforhealth.com/learn/general/ways-to-use-whey/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LIzIyN3Jsh0&feature=youtu.be) by Maangchi, it was used in Korea back in the day to make a popular stew, called Biji Jjigae.

I also found some suggestions that come from the linked [tofu recipe](http://sierraclub.typepad.com/greenlife/2012/12/recipe-tofu-soy-milk-how-to.html).
I have not tried any of them, but I bet it would work great for baking.

- Smoothies / protein shakes
- Baked goods - as a milk replacement
- Soup broths

Comment: @Zanna I don't know what qualities it has that stand out - I'm under an assumption that it has soymilk qualities and thus can be used anywhere that it is used.  I am going to try to make a few things with it to see how they come out.

Comment: hmm soya milk has protein and fats, including omega 3 & 6. I have a feeling soy whey is mostly water, perhaps with a little protein. Actually I'm going to ask a question about this

Answer (score 1):

I coagulate soy milk for tofu using soured whey from a previous batch.  It makes wonderful aromatc tofu and has a much more fibrous texture when frozen.  Put whey in airtight container for 1 1/2 to 2 weeks till surface starts to froth. It must be airtight and it takes a higher volume than other coagulants.  I believe it also has probiotic qualities as other fermentation does. Traditional Vietnamese method!

Comment: Sounds awesome! How do you do that, exactly?

Comment: Just filter off the whey and save in jar.  Nature does the rest :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can make bread with tofu whey or water substitute for other baked goods. You can also use as soup stock for example? Miso soup or Korean biji jjigae (tofu byproduct, aka okara soup. Or even water your plants ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you want lots of biochemical detail supporting terriflys’s answer, read here: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6527785/

I can vouch for soy whey as the liquid in a protein shake. It doesn’t really contribute any perceptible flavor if you’re mixing it with a commercial vegan protein powder.

I have used chickpea cooking water as a substitute for beaten egg whites in waffles; you can actually beat it to a similar color and consistency, but only after aging it for a week or so, at which point it develops a goopy consistency similar to unbeaten egg whites. Can you do something similar with soy whey?